# Bazinga translation bundle returns keys

Tags: symfony, translation

I'm using Symfony 5 and Bazinga translation bundle. This bundle returns keys instead translations.

There is my configuration :

In config\routes\js_translation.yaml :

```
bazinga_js_translation:
    resource: "@BazingaJsTranslationBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml"
```

In assets\js\app.js :

```
import Translator from 'bazinga-translator';
window['Translator'] = Translator;
```

I'm using the translation like this :

```
var message = Translator.trans('want.to.remove.item.confirm.js') + Translator.trans('advert.item.lowercase.js') + '?';
```

There is the keys in translations\messages+intl-icu.en.xlf :

```
<unit id="jJM.l5m" name="want.to.remove.item.confirm.js">
  <segment>
    <source>want.to.remove.item.confirm.js</source>
    <target>Are you sure you want to remove </target>
  </segment>
</unit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is the keys in translations\messages+intl-icu.en.xlf

My assumption is that Bazinga doesn't recognize the `+intl-icu` file extension. Bazinga is an old bundle that hasn't kept up with Symfony features. The ICU message format was added in 4.4 I think and I doubt very much Bazinga supports it.

update (2020-11-10) most recent release of this bundle (4.0.0) includes ability to read `+intl-icu` file extension

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's right. That's the reason.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please mark my answer as the answer to your question. thank you

Comment: @ChristopheDubois the most recent release of this bundle (4.0.0) includes ability to read `+intl-icu` file extension